# General solution to linear PDE with mixed derivatives

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

*Edit: I've reformulated the problem in a way that makes it easier to express the boundary and initial conditions. This involved expressing it in terms of a different function $g(x,t)$ (which was related to the previous formulation as $g_x=f$)*

I'm trying to find a general solution $g(x,t)$ on $0<x<1$, $t>0$ to the following PDE:

$$\rho(g_{xt}+g_{xxt})=(1-\rho)g_{xx}+g_{xxx}$$

where $\rho>0$. Boundary conditions are:

$$\rho(g_t(0,t)+g(0,t))=g_x(0,t)$$

$$g(1,t)=1$$

And the initial condition is $g(x,0)=1$. We also require that

$$\lim_{\rho\to 0}g(x,t)=1$$

If I set the time derivatives to zero I can obtain a steady state solution:

$$g(x)= \frac{\rho e^{x (\rho-1) }-1}{\rho e^{\rho-1 }-1}$$

I am looking for a general solution in $(x,t)$ that converges to the steady-state solution as $t\to\infty$.

Any ideas? I suspect a change of variables is going to make this simpler, but I haven't worked out a good way to do that. Note that by setting $h=g_{x}+g_{xx}$ the PDE can be re-written as:

$$h-g_{x}=\frac{1}{\rho}h_x-h_t$$

which suggests that a change in variables like $u=x+\rho t$ might be a good approach?

Comment: Whoopsie, fixed it now. $f$ is actually a PDF with an atom of probability at x=0. The initial condition is that all the probability is at that point, so $f=0$ everywhere else

Comment: Whats your $x$-domain and boundary conditions?

Comment: OK, I've reformulated it to make everything clearer. See the note at the top.